# how to make a custom shape border like this in flutter , i want to use this shape in toolTip

Tags: flutter, user-interface, tooltip, shapes, user-experience

here i have done something but i need to change the length of the arrow, how to reduce the length of arrow, how to do that in this code.

```
class ToolTipCustomShape extends ShapeBorder {
  final bool usePadding;

  const ToolTipCustomShape({this.usePadding = true});

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions =>
      EdgeInsets.only(bottom: usePadding ? 20 : 0);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) => Path();

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    rect =
        Rect.fromPoints(rect.topLeft, rect.bottomRight - const Offset(0, 20));
    return Path()
      ..addRRect(
          RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(rect.height / 1)))
      ..moveTo(rect.bottomCenter.dx + 90 , rect.bottomCenter.dy)
      ..relativeLineTo(10, 20)
      ..relativeLineTo(10, -20)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

[image]

here i am attaching the image i want to achieve , just like this i want to put this inside a shapeDecoration of toolTip.

Answer (score 0):

You can shift it like

```dart
return Path()
  ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(rect.height / 1)))
  ..moveTo(rect.bottomRight.dx * .7, rect.bottomCenter.dy)
  ..relativeLineTo(10, 20)
  ..relativeLineTo(10, -20)
  ..close();
```

or   `..moveTo(rect.width * .7, rect.bottomCenter.dy)`

```dart
..moveTo(rect.bottomRight.dx - rect.height * .7, rect.bottomCenter.dy) // the one suit you
```

Comment: i have used this code but this doesn't change the length of the arrow instead it changes the position of arrow

Comment: Can you clarify which axis you are trying to change?

Comment: i don't know which axis is that arrow ,   i want to achieve just like the image i have mentioned above , in code  that class should  extends ShapeBorder class. please help

Comment: yes you can put it on ShapeBorder and I've tested it which works fine just looks like triangle expect little curve at bottom, for this you can use quadratic brazier curve